# Sliding panel for mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div which is mostly off page but uses translation on hover to display on the main page.

This is my [site](http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/).

However, on mobile devices this isn't the best solution to display this div. Hover doesn't work well and I have to click often to get it to show up. I'm wondering if it's possible to do it like mobile applications where if I move the page to the right edge enough, this content will display or with a button. Something like this:

[image]

Any thoughts on if this is possible or how'd id solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is called 'Off Canvas layout'. Documented (with some CSS) at http://jasonweaver.name/lab/offcanvas/

There are multiple implementations you could have a look at, perhaps start with this nice demo from Zurb: http://www.zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts

As regards the use of hover, you're better off using a tap/click on both desktop and mobile for consistency. The [3-bar menu button](http://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/) is fairly universally understood these days.

Comment: Thank you I'll look into this. I like the 3-bar menu look. I'll see if i can implement that :/